# Best practice for determining best item statistics combination

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am developing a tool to optimize equipment for a game, and I am not sure how to attack the issue. Its a game that has items such as helmets, armor, and boots. And each item has stats like attack, defense, and health. Any suggestions on how to sort the large array of items to find the best possible combination?

My current idea is to make separate arrays for each item category:

```
helmets = [{id:0, health:100, attack:150}, {} ...];
armor = [{id:23, health:200, attack:70}, {} ...];
```

and then sort each array by a specific stat (find the most Health helmet, most Defense armor). This is obviously a horrible way to sort, leaves room for great items in different categories to be left untouched. I also plan on implementing 'focus filters' as well, so a user can be given items that focus on an attribute like attack or defense.

Overall I'm not really sure what high level strategy to use and how to do this, and am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Weighing each of the stats differently in your sort could help, since I would assume a `{health:1, attack:300}` helmet would be probably considered worse than a `{health:275, attack:275}` one. attack could be worth 1.25x it's points, but you are still adding them into a total

Comment: one up Katamari's comment. Multiplying by a modifier will allow you to filter items based on stat. Id look at possibly using objects rather than arrays and using an ID. You can store all your IDs in a separate array that you can loop over and sort then access the specific item that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best practice is a bit of a dirty term as it's so opinion based.

I was thinking a singleton that wraps your items might be a nice idea. It will allow you to create a useable API that will make your codebase easier to maintain and nicer to look at.

I like to keep data in these types of projects normalised. This means everything is relational and it makes it really easy to access different bits of data in common ways. I created a [REPL for you to play around with](https://repl.it/@mattjbrent/Sorted-Items)

```js
var item = (function () {
  
  var items = {
    helmet: {
      byId: {
        'Helmet of Smiting': {
          id: 'Helmet of Smiting',
          attack: 1000,
          defense: 50
        },
        'Cheap Helmet': {
          id: 'Cheap Helmet',
          attack: 1,
          defense: 2
        },
        'Steel Helmet': {
          id: 'Steel Helmet',
          attack: 50,
          defense: 100
        },
      },
      allIds: ['Helmet of Smiting', 'Cheap Helmet', 'Steel Helmet']
    },
    shield: {
      byId: {
        'Shield of Smiting': {
          id: 'Shield of Smiting',
          attack: 1000,
          defense: 50
        },
        'Cheap Shield': {
          id: 'Cheap Shield',
          attack: 1,
          defense: 2
        },
        'Steel Shield': {
          id: 'Steel Shield',
          attack: 50,
          defense: 100
        },
      },
      allIds: ['Shield of Smiting', 'Cheap Shield', 'Steel Shield']
    }
  };
  
  function sortItems (type, attr) {
    var itemType = items[type];
    // duplicate the items
    var sortedItems = itemType.allIds.slice();
    sortedItems.sort(function (a, b) {
      return itemType.byId[b][attr] - itemType.byId[a][attr];
    });
    return sortedItems;
  }
  
  var itemsConstructor = Object.create({
    add: function (type, id, att, def) {
      items[type].allIds.push(id);
      items[type].byId[id] = {
        id: id,
        attack: att,
        defense: def
      }
    },
    get: function (type, id) {
      if (typeof type === 'undefined') {
        return items;
      } else {
        if (typeof id === 'undefined') {
          return items[type];
        } else {
          return items[type].byId[id];
        }
      }
    },
    getStrongest: function (type, attr) {
      return sortItems(type, attr)[0];
    },
    getStrongestSet: function (attr) {
      var allItemTypes = Object.keys(items);
      var strongestItems = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < allItemTypes.length; ++i) {
        var type = allItemTypes[i];
        strongestItems[type] = sortItems(type, attr)[0];
      }
      return strongestItems;
    }
    
  });
  
  return itemsConstructor;
  
})();

item.add('helmet', 'New Awesome Helmet', 999999, 999999);
console.log(item.getStrongestSet('defense'));
```

Explanation to follow